# Disable dates in <input type="datetime-local">

Tags: html, vue.js

### is there a way to limit dates?

I want to put a date picker so clients can pick a date for an appointment and I wanted to limit dates that are already picked (I have a DB with the appointments and I'm using Vue).

Edit: I can't use min or max for that for obvious reasons

Comment: The only way to limit dates are the min and max attributes on the browser’s native datepicker. To disable specific dates you will need to use a third party datepicker.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you are using the native "datetime-local" you should use the min and max to disable dates outside of your scope 
 
`<input type="datetime-local" id="meeting-time" name="meeting-time" value="2021-12-12T19:30" min="2021-12-07T00:00" max="2021-12-14T00:00">`


You can use an other datepicker except the native one to do it otherwise.